# Installation of rPi Imager failes on Windows 10

Tags: software-installation, windows, win32diskimager

I have 6 Micro SD chips that I want to put various Raspberry Pi Operating Systems on. I tried downloading version 1.6 of the imager from [the official software page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/) twice yesterday. After downloading I tried to install. Both installations failed. The 2 downloads were 2 different sizes, the first was about 16M the second was about 17M.

Norton AV is installed, but it indicates there is no problem with the imager.exe.

My Windows system:

- Processor    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
- Installed RAM    64.0 GB (63.8 GB usable)   System type  64-bit operating
- system, x64-based processor   Pen and touch  No pen or touch input is
- available for this display
- Edition  Windows 10 Pro
- Version  20H2
- Installed on ‎3/‎27/‎2021
- OS build 19042.1165
- Experience   Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3530.0

Has anyone else had this problem, if you have, how did you resolve it?

**Edit based on comments:**
When I attempt to execute imager_1.6.2.exe it fails to completely load, and there is no signature of the software supplier.

This question is cross posted on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1672300/installation-of-rpi-imager-failes-on-windows-10). A comment there is indicating that the download is not completing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with [another "imager"](https://www.saashub.com/raspberry-pi-imager-alternatives) I used [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) to install Ubuntu on a raspberry pi and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this problem if you have a Pi Noob Micro SD.

1. Download Win32 Disk Imager from [Source Forge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).
2. Install Win32 Disk Imager.
3. Clone the Raspberry Pi Noob Micro SD drive to your Windows hard drive. This becomes your permanent backup of Noob.
4. Download BalenaEtcher from [Balena.io](https://www.balena.io/etcher/).
5. Install BalenaEtcher.
6. Flash the New Micro SD drive with the copy of the Raspberry Pi disk image created in step 3.

You can find a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiCCoBiW4E4) to guide you through this.